# Android - Spinner Dialog closes right after opening

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

I use Spinner in my Android application.
When I click to change selected item app opens the corresponding spinner dialog but it closes immediately without any user interaction.

Are there any thoughts what can be the reason?
I can copy the code for the spinner but I think there is no anything extraordinary.

I get the following warning in logcat.

> 09-07 11:22:49.457: D/InputManagerService(120): Window already
>   focused, ignoring focus gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@4059ced0

here is the code in xml layout file. as i said, nothing exraordinar

```
<Spinner
                android:id="@+id/weightMeasure"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/weight_measures" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you posted this a while ago but I had the same issue.  Hopefully someone will find this and it will help.  If you are overriding the onWindowFocusChanged method and setting the content view there then when you open the spinner the focus changes to that spinner so the onWindowFocusChanged method runs and if you set the content view here the spinner will close immediately.

Hope that helps someone.